# How to use an Array as an sql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

I'm trying tu create a function that read from an excel file and put data into a PHP Array .

my question is : it is possible to make a select query from that array , like into LinqToSQL in Vb.Net :
Exemple :

```
Dim list as new List(of Data)
Dim query = From d in list WHERE d.name = "Jon"
```

so my question is : how to use an array as an sql query in php

i hope get some answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a foreach.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    //query here
}
```

Just be mindful that this will query as many times as there are elements in your array.

Or load each element in your array as a query:

```
$array = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column=value;";
array_push($array,$query);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , I m juste tried to find a new and faste way to get data from an array

Comment: foreach is a powerful tool for doing just that. It lets you grab each element and keep track of the index at the same time. You can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php